# fadeIn and fadeOut a children with jQuery when hovering

Tags: jquery, html, hover, children

I'm trying to fadeIn the div .description when I over the parent div .content. I have a couple of those item in my page, so I don't know how to implement the children() in my jQuery code. Right now, when I hover one .content, every .description are faded out.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="description">
            <p>
                <span>Super Garfield</span><br />
                <span>by myself</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url('style/img/body-item-sample1.png')"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="view">
        1234
    </div>
    <div class="like">
        1234
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").hover(function(){
            $(".description").fadeIn(100); // This should set the opacity to 100% on hover
        },function(){
            $(".description").fadeOut(100); // This should set the opacity back to 30% on mouseout
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close. using `$(this)` and [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), you can select the `.description` element only contained within the element that triggered the `.hover()` event. There's a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/xtEDB/). Code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").hover(function() {
        $(this).children(".description").fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $(this).children(".description").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You want the [parent selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) ">"

e.g.:

```
$(".content > .description").fadeIn(100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scpike/Crq64/

Comment: This will fade in _all_ `.description`s inside _any_ `.content`. The OP wants to only fade in content inside the currently hovering element.

Comment: Yea, didn't think about that. Your answer is better

Comment: Thanks. Questions can be a little cryptic sometimes. I think the key to this one is `I have a couple of these on my page`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to go about it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hover(function(){
        $(this).children(".description").fadeIn(100);
    },function(){
        $(this).children(".description").fadeIn(100);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps